# Check if function exists, then run it

Tags: javascript

Is it a correct way to check existence of a function and run it if it is there?

```
this.functions.SomeFunction && this.functions.SomeFunction();
```

I'd prefer to check as simple as

```
if (this.functions.SomeFunction) {this.functions.SomeFunction()}
```

but I saw the first example in the 3rd party code and wonder if it's a good practice or if it's created for some reason like that?

Comment: I think the first example is not clear enough. If another developer will read your code, it will be more easy in the second option.

Comment: All functions in `JavaScript` are first class objects so they are instance of `Object` which under the covers is instance of `Function`. So it is fair enough to check the `typeof` or `this.functions.SomeFunction instanceof Object` or `this.functions.SomeFunction instanceof Function` would be better.

Comment: By relying on the thought "what the hell something other than a function will do within `this.functions`" i would safely do the first. If i still end up something blowing up in my face it is definitely not the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Both do pretty much the same thing. That's the beauty of `&&` operator. It only executes the second `condition` if the first `condition` is true.

Comment: 'truthy' to be precise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof` to do that:

```
if (typeof(theFunction) === "function") {
    theFunction.apply(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify that your function is defined and that is indeed a function you can do the following:

```
if (typeof this.functions.SomeFunction == 'function') { 
  this.functions.SomeFunction(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## we can use **optional chaining**

```
props.onClick?.(args)
```

For Browser compatibility you can visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to check the type of the object, rather then relying on the fact that it is truthy. So: `typeof this.functions.SomeFunction === 'function' && this.functions.SomeFunction()`. The `&&` method is just a shorthand way and is pretty common/widely accepted. Because of boolean logic it won't check the next expression if the first is falsy. And JavaScript will return you the last result of a particular boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer and use in production code is

```
if (typeof this.functions.SomeFunction === 'function') {
  this.functions.SomeFunction()
}
```

Maybe that's better:

```
const { SomeFunction } = this.functions
if (typeof SomeFunction === 'function') {
  SomeFunction()
}
```

And we should make sure `this.functions` exist for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Both are technically correct but in my opinion the second version is better as it is more clear.

Plus you must be really sure that the `SomeFunction` is actually a function to be able to invoke it. In your case is clear as it belongs to a "`functions`" object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to check existence of function

```
if(typeof SomeFunction == 'function') 
   SomeFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is performing an unassigned bitwise calculation which has the side effect of running a function only if it exists. This has the same result as the second, and it looks impressive - but it's like using a pencil to stir your coffee when you have a spoon in front of you.

There is more to coding well than being 'clever'. Personally, I'd say it takes just a moment more to type the second version but it's more readable, easier to debug or put a break point in, and easier to scale when you realise you want to add another command after the if statement.

So long as you and everyone using your code knows why the first option has the same result as the second, then it's your choice. But I've lost count of the number of times I've done a clever bit of shorthand, and then had to turn it into a good old fashioned if statement within a few minutes to work out why it's not firing correctly.